# sql concatenate values of an array of jsons

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

In mysql, I have a table with a json column of example data:

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "apple", "amount": 3},
        {"id": 3, "name": "banana", "amount": 5}
    ]
}
```

how to i get a column of concatenated values of fruit ids?

expected result value: `"1,3"`

I tried:
`select json_value(col, '$.fruits[*].id') as ids from table`
but resulted in a column of null values.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using JSON for this data? Would it be simpler if you stored the data in a second table `fruits` with columns `id`, `name`, `amount`?

Comment: @BillKarwin I need multiple arrays of ordered `fruits`(100+), and making each one into a table would make it harder to access/manage them at once.

Comment: also, turning the array into a table and using incremented ids to order the elements would make it harder to manually add or remove elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_table`:

```
select group_concat(t1.val) from tbl t 
cross join json_table(t.js, '$.fruits[*]' columns(val text path '$.id')) t1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-XeBgfsG)